# Sphinx generated documentation is not showing messages of logger (python code block)

Tags: python, logging, ipython, python-sphinx, python-logging

I have a piece of python code that returns an INFO message using the logging package (`logging.info(f"Parameter already present.")`). But when I run that code in a python code block (using the `.. ipython:: python` directive), the log-message is not shown. Or with an even smaller MWE:

```
.. ipython:: python
  
  import logging
  logging.info("test logging")
  print("test print")
```

Only gives the output of the print statement ("test print"). How can I make Sphinx show the logging message?

Answer (score 0):

Set the logging level to INFO (the default is WARNING) and ensure that the stdout stream is used. This works for me:

```
.. ipython:: python
  
   import logging, sys
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
   logging.info("test logging")
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed this works (which is one step further). However, when I put this in the `__init__.py` of my package called `hgc` and I use the following snippet, in an ipython block in my rst file, it doesn't work:
`    import hgc;    logging.info("test logging")`